# .NET C# GUI application Command line

Tags: c#, user-interface, command-line

I am trying to use the command line arguments in a GUI (.NET + WPF) C#  application. I've read that in VB.NET exists something like `My.Application.CommandLineArgs` but I haven´t found the C# equivalent.

I have hacked the Main function in the application class to include the string[] argv parameter and pass it to the application class constructor but i don't think that will be the correct way to access the command line parameters.

What is the correct way to access it in a C# GUI WPF application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declaring `argv` in `Main` is fine, and is quite commonly used. [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) allows access to them at any time (declaring `argv` etc. is optional). [Environment.CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) is a lower level function which gets the raw commandline prior to its being parsed (and the exe name getting transformed etc.).

Comment: `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` can be used without declaring argv in a gui app btw, for future visitors.

Comment: @MDMoore313 Thanks, gobbled in!

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, this will give you the command line parameters.